# Insertar data a 3 tabla a la vez

Tags: api, spring, eclipse, rest

he creado mis entidades Teacher, Course, SocialMedi Y TeacherSocialMedia. En mi tabla  TeacherSocialMedia tiene campos que se relacionan con Teacher y socialMedia ya que recibe el id de cada tabla como fk , quiero que al crear un taecher, se cree también un registro en TeacherSocialMedia , ya cree mi dao y mis services  ¿cómo iria el código en mi controller y como seria el json para insertar ?

este es model teacher

```
package com.ebim.teachers.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="profesor")
public class Teacher implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer tea_id;
    public String tea_nam;
    public String tea_ava;
    
    public Teacher() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public Teacher(String tea_nam, String tea_ava) {
        super();
        this.tea_nam = tea_nam;
        this.tea_ava = tea_ava;
    }
    public Integer getTea_id() {
        return tea_id;
    }
    public void setTea_id(Integer tea_id) {
        this.tea_id = tea_id;
    }
    public String getTea_nam() {
        return tea_nam;
    }
    public void setTea_nam(String tea_nam) {
        this.tea_nam = tea_nam;
    }
    public String getTea_ava() {
        return tea_ava;
    }
    public void setTea_ava(String tea_ava) {
        this.tea_ava = tea_ava;
    }
}
```

este es model social_media

```
package com.ebim.teachers.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="red_social")
public class SocialMedia implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer sm_id;
    public String sm_name;
    public String sm_icom;
    
    public SocialMedia() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public SocialMedia(String sm_name, String sm_icom) {
        super();
        this.sm_name = sm_name;
        this.sm_icom = sm_icom;
    }

    public Integer getSm_id() {
        return sm_id;
    }
    public void setSm_id(Integer sm_id) {
        this.sm_id = sm_id;
    }
    public String getSm_name() {
        return sm_name;
    }
    public void setSm_name(String sm_name) {
        this.sm_name = sm_name;
    }
    public String getSm_icom() {
        return sm_icom;
    }
    public void setSm_icom(String sm_icom) {
        this.sm_icom = sm_icom;
    }
}
```

este es el model TeacherSocialMedia

```
package com.ebim.teachers.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="relacion_redesSociales")
public class TeacherSocialMedia implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer tsm_id; //primary key
    public Integer tsm_id_teacher; //fk teacher
    public Integer tsm_id_sm; //socil media fk
    public String tsm_nic;
    
    public TeacherSocialMedia() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public TeacherSocialMedia(Integer tsm_id_teacher, Integer tsm_id_sm, String tsm_nic) {
        super();
        this.tsm_id_teacher = tsm_id_teacher;
        this.tsm_id_sm = tsm_id_sm;
        this.tsm_nic = tsm_nic;
    }

    public Integer getTsm_id() {
        return tsm_id;
    }
    public void setTsm_id(Integer tsm_id) {
        this.tsm_id = tsm_id;
    }
    public Integer getTsm_id_teacher() {
        return tsm_id_teacher;
    }
    public void setTsm_id_teacher(Integer tsm_id_teacher) {
        this.tsm_id_teacher = tsm_id_teacher;
    }
    public Integer getTsm_id_sm() {
        return tsm_id_sm;
    }
    public void setTsm_id_sm(Integer tsm_id_sm) {
        this.tsm_id_sm = tsm_id_sm;
    }
    public String getTsm_nic() {
        return tsm_nic;
    }
    public void setTsm_nic(String tsm_nic) {
        this.tsm_nic = tsm_nic;
    }
}
```

este es mis servicio implementado de teacher

```
package com.ebim.teachers.servicesImpl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.ebim.teachers.dao.ITeacherDao;
import com.ebim.teachers.models.Teacher;
import com.ebim.teachers.services.ITeacherService;

public class TeacherSeviceImpl implements ITeacherService{

    @Autowired
    private ITeacherDao iTeacherDao;
    
    @Override
    public Teacher newTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return iTeacherDao.save(teacher);
    }
}
```

este es mi servicio implementado de socialMedia

```
package com.ebim.teachers.servicesImpl;

import java.util.List;

import com.ebim.teachers.dao.ISocialMediaDao;
import com.ebim.teachers.models.SocialMedia;
import com.ebim.teachers.services.ISocialMediaService;

public class SocialMediaServiceImpl implements ISocialMediaService{
    
    private ISocialMediaDao iSocialMediaDao;

    @Override
    public SocialMedia newSocialMedia(SocialMedia socialMedia) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return iSocialMediaDao.save(socialMedia);
    }
}
```

este es mi servicio implementado de teacherSocialMedia

```
package com.ebim.teachers.servicesImpl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ebim.teachers.dao.ITeacherSocialMediaDao;
import com.ebim.teachers.models.TeacherSocialMedia;
import com.ebim.teachers.services.ITeacherSocialMediaService;

@Service
public class TeacherSocialMediaServiceImpl implements ITeacherSocialMediaService{

    @Autowired
    private ITeacherSocialMediaDao iTeacherSocialMediaDao;
    
    @Override
    public void newTsm(List<TeacherSocialMedia> listaTsm) {
        iTeacherSocialMediaDao.saveAll(listaTsm);
    }
}
```

este es mi controller

```
package com.ebim.teachers.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ebim.teachers.models.TeacherSocialMedia;
import com.ebim.teachers.servicesImpl.TeacherSocialMediaServiceImpl;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/profesores")
public class TeacherController {
    
    @Autowired
    private TeacherSocialMediaServiceImpl teacherSocialMediaServiceImpl;
    
    @PostMapping("/insertar")
    public void crearDetalle(List<TeacherSocialMedia> listaTsm) {
        teacherSocialMediaServiceImpl.newTsm(listaTsm);
    }
}
```

Comment: el metodo  ```save``` del repository retornan la entidad guardada, por lo que podrías usar el retorno de ```Teacher``` para crear tu registro ```TeacherSocialMedia``` y guardarlo

Comment: Para  relacionar tus entidades usa la notación [@ManytoOne](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many), para añadir los fk

Comment: @Charls la notación ManytoOne iría en las columnas que se relaciona? y como haría  para al enviar el json ingrese en ambas tablas , y que retorne el resultado de ambas